# User Control on a WebPart, PostBack / ViewState Problem

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, user-controls, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I'm using a Sharepoint WebPart to load a UserControl which has a button that does some processing on PostBack. I got a problem: when I click the button for the first time, the data loaded on ! IsPosback gets lost, but this does not occur when I click the button again. I think my problem is explained here: [Sharepoint Lifecycle](http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/sharepoint-webpart-lifecycle-events/), but I haven't been able to find a workaround.

Any help would be really appreciated.

**Additional Info:**
I'm using EnsureChildControls on the WebPart's OnLoad event, and loading the UserControl on CreateChildControls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by programatically specifying an ID to the User Control.

E.g.:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ID = "MyUserControlID";
}
```

More info here: http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/314816-dynamically-loaded-control-event-only-reached-2nd-postback

Comment: This was a fix for me too! I have been trying to figure this out for 3 days! I kept loosing my values on postbacks. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    if (ViewState["MyStuff"] == null)
        LoadMyStuffAndSaveToViewState();
    else
        DoSomethingWith(ViewState["MyStuff"]);
}
```